# Browser showing certificate selection box only once

Tags: authentication, ssl, browser, client-certificates

I'm using certificate authentication on one website.

On the first access, the browser is showing the dialog box "Certificate Selection" (I have several certificates installed on my computer).
If I'm selecting the wrong certificate, the problem is that the browser will never allowing me to select another certificate (it presents the previously selected certificate to the website)... the only option is to restart the browser.

Tested with Chrome and Edge.

So my question is: is it possible (maybe from the server by sending some http headers?) asking the browser to show this dialog again?

Current .htaccess file content is:

```
SSLOptions +StrictRequire +StdEnvVars +OptRenegotiate
SSLVerifyClient require
SSLVerifyDepth 5

SSLRequire %{SSL_CLIENT_I_DN_CN} in { "myCA" }
```

Comment: Could you post the code you are using?

Comment: .htaccess content added to question :)